# Help needed for extending Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

As most of you would know, if I drop a file named app_offline.htm in the root of an asp.net application, it takes the application offline [as detailed here](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/04/aspnet-20-features-appofflinehtm.html).

You would also know, that while this is great, IIS actually returns a 404 code when this is in process and Microsoft is not going to do anything about it [as mentioned here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=319986).

Now, since Asp.Net in general is so extensible, I am thinking that shouldn't there be a way to over ride this status code to return a 503 instead? The problem is, I don't know where to start looking to make this change.

HELP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handling of app_offline.htm is hardcoded in the ASP.NET pipeline, and can't be modified: see `CheckApplicationEnabled()` in `HttpRuntime.cs`, where it throws a very non-configurable 404 error if the application is deemed to be offline.

However, [creating your own HTTP module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) to do something similar is of course trivial -- the OnBeginRequest handler could look as follows in this case (implementation for a HttpHandler shown, but in a HttpModule the idea is exactly the same):

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal ctx As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    If IO.File.Exists(ctx.Server.MapPath("/app_unavailable.htm")) Then
        ctx.Response.Status = "503 Unavailable (in Maintenance Mode)"
        ctx.Response.Write(String.Format("<html><h1>{0}</h1></html>", ctx.Response.Status))
        ctx.Response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is just a starting point, of course: by making the returned HTML a bit friendlier, you can display a nice "we'll be right back" page to your users as well.

Comment: That, I guess, is what I was hoping is not the case. I think I read in a Scott Gu article that there are events exposed by the pipeline for something like this. Now, I wonder if it really is hard coded.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely hardcoded. I've updated my answer to include the function name and source file in the ASP.NET reference source that shows that quite clearly...

Answer (score 2):

You can try turning it off in the web.config.

```
<httpRuntime enable = "False"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it by writing your own HTTP Handler (a .NET component that implements the System.Web.IHttpHandler interface).

There's a good primer article here:
[link text](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm)

Comment: That won't work, right? Because this technique doesn't even let the App Domain load, so I am thinking that the HTTP Handler will never get called.

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of app_offline.htm and httpRuntime enable = "False", highlighted in the 1st link in the original question, is that the app domain of the application is no longer loaded, which may be desirable for substantial site changes. A slight modification to leppie's answer (which still serves 404's) is to add a defaultRedirect to another website which would allow the source site to be in the shut down state, the target site would then serve a simple 503 generating page

web.config source site

```
<httpRuntime enable="false" />
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/maintainance.aspx"/>
```

maintainance.aspx in dest site

```
<%@Page Language="C#"%>
<% 
    Response.StatusCode = 503;
    Response.Write("App offline for maintainance"); 
%>
```